# Understanding the "Cow Id" coding competition solution

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I understand the DP part of the solution, but I don't understand the "trace back" part, and also how does finding the number of j length numbers with i set bits help solve the problem? The bolded part of the solution is what is confusing me.

**Problem:**

```
Being a secret computer geek, Farmer John labels all of his cows with
binary numbers. However, he is a bit superstitious, and only labels cows
with binary numbers that have exactly K "1" bits (1 <= K <= 10).  The
leading bit of each label is always a "1" bit, of course. FJ assigns
labels in increasing numeric order, starting from the smallest possible
valid label -- a K-bit number consisting of all "1" bits. Unfortunately,
he loses track of his labeling and needs your help: please determine the
Nth label he should assign (1 <= N <= 10^7).

INPUT FORMAT:

* Line 1: Two space-separated integers, N and K.

SAMPLE INPUT (file cowids.in):

7 3

INPUT DETAILS:

Among all binary numbers containing exactly 3 "1" bits, FJ wants to output
the 7th in increasing sorted order.

SAMPLE OUTPUT (file cowids.out):

10110
```

**Solution:**

> This problem can be solved by dynamic programming. We treat inputs with K=1 as a special case, since this involves just printing a one followed by N-1 zeros. For K at least 2, a quick back-of-the-envelope calculation shows us that the total number of digits in the answer will be at most 5000. For the two-dimensional array A[0..10][0..5000], we let A[i][j] denote the number of j-digit binary numbers (including those that start with leading zeros) with exactly i 1-bits. We can fill in this table by setting A[i][j] = A[i-1][j-1] + A[i][j-1], since a j-digit number with i 1-bits can be obtained either by appending a 0 bit to a (j-1)-digit number with i 1-bits, or by appending a 1 bit to a (j-1)-digit number with (i-1) 1-bits. **Once we have filled in the table, the appropriate "traceback path" from A[K][5000] gives us the binary number we seek (taking care not to print leading zeros).**
>   "

**Solution Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 5000

int A[11][M+1];
int leading_zeros = 1;

void print_sol(int n,int k,int m)
{
  if (k==0 && m==1) return;
  if (k==0 || A[k][m-1] >= n) {
    if (!leading_zeros) printf ("0");
    print_sol(n,k,m-1);
  } else {
    leading_zeros = 0;
    printf ("1");
    print_sol(n-A[k][m-1],k-1,m-1);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int i,j,N,K;

  freopen ("cowids.in", "r", stdin);
  freopen ("cowids.out", "w", stdout);

  scanf ("%d %d", &N, &K);

  if (K==1) {
    printf ("1");
    for (i=0; i<N-1; i++) printf ("0");
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
  }

  A[0][1] = 1;
  for (j=1; j<=M; j++) {
    for (i=0; i<=10; i++) {
      if (i==0) A[i][j] = 1;
      else A[i][j] = A[i-1][j-1] + A[i][j-1];
      if (A[i][j] > 10000000) A[i][j] = 10000000; /* avoid overflow */
    }
  }

  print_sol(N,K,M);
  printf ("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is "2012 USACO Cow Id (silver)" a coding competition?

Comment: @halfer The [USA Computing Olympiad](http://usaco.org/) is a programming competition for high school students used to select the members of the USA team for the [International Olympiad in Informatics](https://ioinformatics.org/).

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, I have made the title less cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've briefly annotated the solution code. I'm not giving away the answer, rather I'm leaving it as a brain workout (good practice). If there's anything that I fail to explain or explain too vaguely, I'll revise my annotation.

```
void print_sol(int n,int k,int m)
{
  if (k==0 && m==1) // base case
    return;
  if (k==0 || A[k][m-1] >= n) { // If there are more than n numbers that satisfy A[k][m-1], we can afford to decrease the number of digits in the answer.
    if (!leading_zeros) printf ("0"); // don't print 0's if they lead the number (i.e. 0001 is wrong)
    print_sol(n,k,m-1); // decrement number of digits, m
  } else {
    leading_zeros = 0; // There is no longer a need to consider leading 0's 
                       // because we are gonna print a "1". Notice there's no code "leading_zeros = 0"?
                       // That's because once we've printed the first "1", we don't have to worry about leading 0's.
    printf ("1");
    print_sol(n-A[k][m-1],k-1,m-1); // We just printed a 1-bit, so we only need to print k-1 more 1's.
                                    // Decrement m since we just printed out a digit.
                                    // We initially had to find the n-th number with k 1-bits, but we just took care of a few by printing that "1". Decrease n.
                                    // In basic terms, this line is saying "print out the n-A[k][m-1]-largest number with m-1 digits and k-1 1-bits"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about coding competitions - my brain is too slow - but is there advantage in swapping out the short var names to something meaningful? When programming is taught, we always say "use meaningful variable names" in order to improve maintainability. Is there a general exception for coding competitions?

Comment: @halfer I personally try to make my variable names clear. There are some competitive coders that just focus on spitting out code fast with short variable names (especially since this code likely won’t be used ever again). In this Cow ID question, however, I feel the variables are clear enough.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding @Felix Hu, and also nice explanation